# Can't find path to sdcard

Tags: android, path, android-sdcard

I have Sony Xperia M2Dual Android 4.4.4. I try get path to my sdcard.
All paths what I tried get

**/mnt/***

**/storage/***

And others

```js
File[] list = (new File("/mnt/sdcard")).listFiles();

for(File f : list){
     Log.i("bairro", f.getPath());
}
```

I get error NullPointException.

Comment: You do not have arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+.

Comment: Well that is only half the story. With the right permission an app can read all.

Comment: But what I need do to get access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `/mnt/sdcard`  use

```
File[] list = (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString())).listFiles();
```

and also need permission for External storage access in manifest

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
File[] list = (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath())).listFiles();
        Log.d("Length", String.valueOf(list.length));

        for(File f : list){
             Log.i("bairro", f.getPath());
        }
```